# What is a "two-frame punish?"

Tags: terminology, super-smash-bros-4

I often see phrases like "two-frame punish" when watching Super Smash Bros 4 tournaments. I often see it when people are edge guarding, and it some how prevents players from grabbing the edge. What does this mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out by @Nelson, I did some quick research and found the answer from [Smashpedia](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/Two_Frame_Punish):

> The Two Frame Punish is a mechanic and technique in Super Smash Bros. for Nintendo 3DS and Wii U, in which an edge-guarder's attack is timed in order to punish the opponent on the two frames of vulnerability that occur at the beginning of a ledge grab animation.

Comment: Just FYI. "x-frame punish", where 'x' can be any number,  in general means the amount of frames of vulnerability of which the opponent or you can't block or do anything. The "two-frame punish" is what the Sm4sh community calls the ledge punish. "two-frame punish" can mean other things in other fighting games.